# How to share multiple images dynamically using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dynamic, share

I have dynamic image list. In which i have added multiple images from my JSON Response. how can i share all images dynamically to another Application using Flutter.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share/example try this plugin bro, this plugin will solve your problem.

Comment: It will not share the image list coming from json api

Comment: you will get image url from api, then see example code for _shareImageFromUrl method